# Webpack with babel-loader not able to parse react function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm in the middle of a huge project refactor which I have to upgrade a bunch of libraries however I'm struggling with an error whenever I try to compile the project with webpack:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sequoia-react-component-library/src/containers/ConnectedSignIn/index.js 12:31
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:31)
File was processed with these loaders:
* ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
> const errorWrapper = props => (<div className='errors'>{ props.children }</div>);
| 
| const getValidityClass = ({ fieldValue }) => {
@ ./src/views/sign-in/sign-in.js 34:0-93 70:46-61
@ ./src/views/sign-in/index.js
@ ./src/App.js
@ ./src/loader.js
@ ./src/index.js
@ multi ./src/index.js
```

So it turns out that it has to do with the babel-loader configuration which I have configured as follows:

```
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
```

And **babel.config.json**:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env", 
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]

}
```

I thought at first it was a problem with the different babel files configuration. I tried first with **.babelrc** but the doc states that only works for single file project configurations rather than wide projects configuration which **babel.config.json** can manage it but it turns out that works pretty good with all the root files but not the ones placed within **node_modules**. I don't know what could I missing and I don't know how really babel apply the rules in term to watch for the files to parse and transpile.

Someone who could throw me some light?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your babel and react versions?

Comment: Of course, these are the version I got:

@babel/core: 7.11.6
@babel/preset-env: 7.11.5
@babel/preset-react: 7.0.0
react: 16.13.1
babel-loader:  8.0.6

Comment: I'm guessing that `sequoia-react-component-library` has some jsx that is not transpiled. and since your exluding all of node_modules it is not transformed.

Comment: Try changing your file extension to `.js`, that fixed it for me temporarily

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
  /* removed exclude: /node_modules/, */
  loader: "babel-loader"
},
```

Since the broken file is inside a node module, try commenting the exclude and that should transpile those react files as well.